# emailmultialternatives attach file and html content in django

Tags: python, django

I tried to use the `EmailMultiAlternatives` to send an email in `html` and 
a text. I also want to include a file to this email.

But the later seems to erase my html content.

Here is my code :

```
msg = EmailMultiAlternatives(subject, html2text(html_content), 
list(email_from), list(email_to), 
attachments=((request.session['customer']+".txt.blowfish", 
request.session["customer"].content),)) 

msg.attach_alternative(html_content, "text/html") 

msg.send()
```

I use the latest SVN revision 
I also tried using `msg.attact()` instead of attachments, same result!

The alternative text content is sent, but the html one is not. It only 
show the file.

Any clue would be much appreciated,

Comment: Docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/email/#sending-alternative-content-types

Answer (score 16):

I had the same issue!

The code I used to attach a file to a HTML email is:

```
email_dict = {}
email_dict['user'] = user                       

t = loader.get_template('emails/myemail.html')
html = t.render(Context(email_dict))

msg = EmailMultiAlternatives(subject='My Subject', 
                             body=html, 
                             from_email=settings.DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL, 
                             to=['my_email@email.com'],) 

attachment = open('filepath', 'rb')
msg.attach('Name.txt', attachment.read(), 'text/csv')

msg.content_subtype = 'html'
msg.send()
```

So perhaps something like this could work for you:

```
msg = EmailMultiAlternatives(subject=subject, 
                             body=html2text(html_content), 
                             from_email=list(email_from), 
                             to=list(email_to))


attachment = open(request.session['customer']+".txt.blowfish", 'rb')
msg.attach('Name.txt.blowfish', attachment.read(), 'text/plain')

msg.content_subtype = 'html'
msg.send()
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: Just so perfect answer..!